# Having a default value in ng-options in angularjs but also having persistence when we get back to the form again

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, ng-options

My current scenario is i query a service and bring an array of values and display it in dropdown in AngularJS using ng-options. The problem is i need a default value at the top of the dropdown somthing like "Select from the list".

I have done that using

```
<option value="">Select from the options</option>
```

the problem is i also need to persist the data when i select suppose first value in the dropdown and go to some other page for sometime and come back to the same page which has that dropdown. That time i again need to see the first item selected and not the "Select from the options" thing.

How can i add this text "Select from the options" to the array which comes after querying a service and populates the dropdown also maintaining the persistence using ngModel.

Thanks,
MK

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the "other page" is still in the same (single-page) Angular application, you can store the selection in a factory and when you come back to the page, initialize the ngModel object (in the controller) by reading it from the factory. There are many ways, but this is one of the usual basic patterns in Angular.

If the visit to the "other page" causes Angular to be reloaded, one typical approach is to store the settings in local storage.